# KDE - Application menu not displaying correct icon

Tags: kubuntu, kde, launcher, icons, desktop-environments

In below screenshot you can see that in the application menu, under the development tag, the icons are not correct, however, on the taskbar the icons are correct:

[image]

I checked the `~/.local/share/applications` directory and these 3 applications have a valid entry.
The "Icon" property of the .desktop files is also correct and pointing towards a valid ".svg" file. How can I tell the application menu to display the correct icon?

## Edit 1

Below my plasma version:

```
xxx@dell:~$ plasmashell --version
plasmashell 5.12.9
```

## Edit 2

Below is one relevant .desktop file for IntelliJ (~/local/share/applications/jetbrains-ide.desktop):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=Development;IDE;
Comment[en_US]=Capable and ergonomic Java IDE
Comment=Capable and ergonomic Java IDE
Exec="/home/xxx/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/193.6911.18/bin/idea.sh" %f
GenericName[en_US]=
GenericName=
Icon=/home/xxx/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-U/ch-0/icon.svg
MimeType=
Name[en_US]=IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate
Name=IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate
Path=
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-idea
Terminal=false
TerminalOptions=
Type=Application
Version=1.0
X-DBUS-ServiceName=
X-DBUS-StartupType=
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
X-KDE-Username=
```

What's funny is that the comment and categorie for example are indeed updating. But not the icon.

## Edit 3

One weird thing I also figured out is that when opening below menu, the icon is "loaded" into a preview (to open `click right mouse on app -> Edit application...` :
[image]

Comment: You could try `kbuildsycoca4`- I've had to use it in the past to sort out the K menu (but the usual problem for me is it just empties.)

Comment: @B.Tanner Just tried it, does not fix the issue...

Comment: @DKBose I updated my question providing the reader with the installed plasma version. Trying other icon themes still is not giving me the result I want. It's even worse, with some icon themes ALL icons are blank... That's why I stick to Breeze.

Comment: @DKBose I just updated my question...

Comment: I want the exact names of the `.svg` entries as listed in the `Icon=` lines from your .desktop files.

Comment: @DKBose sorry for the delay, just refreshed the edit page.

Comment: How did you install these applications? You seem to have used an icon that isn't part of the Breeze icon set.

Comment: For icons to show up everywhere, they may have to be available to the system in various sizes. Look at the Breeze icon set for guidance.

Comment: @DKBose I installed Android Studio and IntelliJ using the JetBrains Toolbox (link: https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/)

Comment: @DKBose That is weird, since it does display the icons in the task bar (panel) + those applications only come with a .svg icon. So no various sizes available... What do you suggest?

Comment: As an AppImage or from a .tar.gz? If from the latter, it's possible that not all the sizes are available to the system.

Comment: as a tar.gz, since there was not really another option, or did I oversee some option?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't use those applications and so can't help.

Comment: @DKBose There is one funny thing that I am going to put into "Edit 3". Maybe you could help me there?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.
It seems that launcher cannot show the svg file.

I solved it with converting .icon.svg file to ico format. Then changed the program icon.